# Cannot convert value of type '(_) throws -> ()' to expected argument type '((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?'

Tags: ios, swift

First of all, thank you so much for helping me. I do not understand this error and am unable to find a solution.

I have looked at other answers but they didn't seem to help. Here is my code. The error shows up on the let action line.

```
  @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    var textField = UITextField()

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Todoey Item", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)


    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add item", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in





        //what will happen once the user clicks the Add Item button on our UIAlert

        let newItem = item()
        newItem.title = textField.text!
        self.itemArray.append(newItem)

   let encoder = PropertyListEncoder()

        do {

        let data = try encoder.encode(self.itemArray)
        }

        catch {

            try Data.write(to: self.dataFilePath!)
            print("Error encoding item array, \(error)")

        }


        //reloads table view data
        self.tableView.reloadData()

      }

alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in

        alertTextField.placeholder = "What Needs To Be Done?"
      textField = alertTextField
    }

alert.addAction(action)
  present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

> Error:  Cannot convert value of type '(_) throws -> ()' to expected argument type '((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?'

Comment: post full code where you get that error

Comment: @Cathal Is your issue fixed now ?

Comment: I just posted my full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three issues:

1. The parameter in the action must be an instance, not a type

   ```
   let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add item", style: .default) { action in
   ```

   or if the action is unused

   ```
   let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add item", style: .default) { _ in
   ```
2. `Data.write(to:..` must be `data.write(to:..`
3. The third issue causes the (a bit misleading) error message: the `data` line must be inside the `do` block. The error indicates that there is no `do` block around the `try` statement

   ```
   do {
       let data = try encoder.encode(self.itemArray)
       try data.write(to: self.dataFilePath!)
    }
    catch {
       print("Error encoding item array, \(error)")
   }
   ```